# Play App Signing for further Alpha tack upload

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-signing

I am trying to leverage Google's Play App Signing for existing android application. At this point under Google Play Console/Setup/App Integrity I have

1. 'App signing key certificate'
2. 'Upload key certificate'
3. Also I have produced update jks file using pepk.jar tool
   How do I sign the application now, in order to upload it to, say, Alpha track?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are already enrolled in Play Signing.

When you enrolled, one of two things happened:

- Either you provided a certificate for the upload key, in which case you should sign your app with the keystore that was used to create the certificate,
- Or you didn't provide a certificate for the upload key, in which case, the upload certificate should be the same as the app signing certificate (you can verify this if the fingerprints shown for "app signing certificate" and "upload certificate" are the same on the App Integrity page), and you can keep signing your app with the same keystore as before.

Comment: thanks from what I understood I can update my original jks with upload certificate or may be even create new jks, update it with upload certificate and communicate that with Google, but what is the purpose here? I was trying to avoid storing jks on my CI. Upvoting for paying attention to this.

Comment: You have nothing to update or create. You already have the keystore to sign your APK/Bundles. Either you created it when you enrolled, or it's the same as before.
The purpose of an upload key is to decouple it from the signing key, so that if your upload key is compromised, you can reset it while it isn't possible to reset your signing key. This is why it's encouraged to use a different upload key than a signing key. 
I'd encourage to read the documentation to understand more how this works: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756